# dynamic table references with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel table called "groups" where the headers are group names. In the column below the group name are the members of that specific group.

In another table I have all member names in the first column and the group names in the first row. And I want to check for each member name whether it is in the group above.

To check whether Tim is in the group "guys" I could use the formula:

```
=if( countif( groups[guys];"Tim")>0;"yes";"no")
```

But I have a command button "add group" which opens a userform where I can enter a new group + members. The name of the new group is entered into textbox1. The group and member are added to the groups table.

I want the 2nd table to update as well. What I would like to do is something like this:

```
With Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("PersonIsInGroupTab")
    .ListColumns.Add Position:=3
    .HeaderRowRange(3).Value = TextBox1.Value
    .DataBodyRange(1, 3).formula= "=if( countif( groups[textbox1.value];""Tim"")>0;""yes"",""no"")" 
End With
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

`textbox1.value` is the name of the new group (also added to the groups tab).

Is there a way I can make this work?

EDIT:
I tried another approach that didn't work either but might help answering the question.
In the table that checks whether a certain person is a member of a group I start by default with one group. And manually enter the formula

```
=if(countif(groups[guys],"Tim")>0,"yes","no")
```

into the cell (in my case J4). When I add a group "gals" using the userform I get a second column "gals" in my table. When I manually drag the formula from the [guys] cell to the [gals] cell (K4) it works just as I want it to. And I get the formula

```
=if(countif(groups[gals],"Tim)>0,"yes","no")
```

in the gals cell (K4)
So I figured I could just do this autofill in VBA as part of the "add group" routine. This is the code I used:

```
Range("groups[guys]").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J4:K4"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I got this code from recording the autofill as a macro. But when I run it the formula in K4 is just as in J4, with groups[guys] instead of groups[gals].
I cant do Destination:=Range("groups[[guys]:[gals]]") as I want it to be working with any groupname not only gals.

Comment: Is there any specific error you get?

Comment: runtime error 1004 in  .DataBodyRange(1, 3).formula= "=if( countif( groups[textbox1.value];"Tim")>0;"yes";"no")". I suppose I cannot reference  in that way. textbox1.value is received from a textbox in a userform. If textbox1.value= group1 then groups[group1] would work. Unfortunately I dont know textbox1.value in advance.

Comment: The formula is incorrect and needs to be revised. (1) replace single " with double "" within the formula like so `"=if( countif( groups[textbox1.value];""Tim"")>0;""yes"";""no"")" `. (2) you are using a non-English Excel version. Still, within VBA all formulas must be passed in English format. So, you need to replace the ; with , like so: `"=if( countif( groups[textbox1.value],""Tim"")>0,""yes"",""no"")"`. That should work better.

Comment: Thx! I corrected those errors. But the issue remains ;( I also noticed: When I hover my mouse courser over TextBox1.value in the line in question it does not show its value. It does in other lines. Does this mean VBA doesnt recognize textbox1.value within a table reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by writing a VBA function instead of using countif.
The function is:

```
Function IsInGroup(group, member As String) As Boolean
For Each Item In group
    If Item = member Then
        IsInGroup = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next Item
IsInGroup = False
End Function
```

And I used it like this:

```
temparray = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("groups").ListColumns(2).Range
With Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("PersonIsInGroupTab")
    tempmember = .DataBodyRange(1, 1).Value
    .ListColumns.Add Position:=3
    .HeaderRowRange(3).Value = TextBox1.Value
    .DataBodyRange(1, 3).Value = IsInGroup(temparray, tempmember)
End With
```